# the derivative of cos(2x) with the double-angle formula?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So, last minute my teacher posted something saying to study double-angle formulas for our derivative test tomorrow. So in the back of the book it shows three things for $\cos x$

1. $2 \cos^2 x$
2. $1-2\sin^2 x$
3. $\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x$

So I am not sure which one of these to use, and do I just find the derivative of them afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

Use whichever you want as

$$\frac{d(1-2\sin^2x)}{dx}=\frac{d(1)}{dx}-2\frac{d(\sin^2x)}{d(\sin x)}\cdot\frac{d(\sin x)}{dx}=0-2(2\sin x)\cos x=-2\sin2x$$

Similarly, 
$$\frac{d(2\cos^2x-1)}{dx}=\cdots=2(2\cos x)(-\sin x)$$

Can you try
$$\frac{d(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)}{dx}?$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$cos(2x) = cos(x+x) = cos(x)cos(x) - sin(x)sin(x) = cos^2(x) - sin^2(x)$.

The derivative is ...

${d \over dx}(cos^2(x)-sin^2(x))$

$={d \over dx}cos^2(x) - {d \over dx}sin^2(x)$

$=-2cos(x)sin(x) - 2sin(x)cos(x)$

$= -4sin(x)cos(x)$

Comment: So the other two in the book are just steps showing how to get to the cos-sin part?